# PHP SimpleXML how to access data

Tags: php, simplexml

I have an XML but I can't seem to access any of the nodes.

When I use the code below I can see it is picking up the data but I can't seem to access the nodes individually.

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("uploads/" . $fileName) or die("Error: can't create     object");
echo'<pre>';
print_r($xml);
echo'</pre>';
```

Here is a sample record.

```
<CONSOLIDATED_LIST xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<INDIVIDUALS>
<INDIVIDUAL   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="">
<DATAID>110404</DATAID>
<VERSIONNUM>1</VERSIONNUM>
<FIRST_NAME>MOHAMMAD BAQER</FIRST_NAME>
<SECOND_NAME>ZOLQADR</SECOND_NAME>
<UN_LIST_TYPE>Iran</UN_LIST_TYPE>
<REFERENCE_NUMBER>IRi.043</REFERENCE_NUMBER>
<LISTED_ON>2007-03-24</LISTED_ON>
<COMMENTS1>[Old Reference # I.47.D.7]</COMMENTS1>
<DESIGNATION>
<VALUE>General/IRGC officer</VALUE>
<VALUE>Deputy Interior Minister for Security Affairs</VALUE>
</DESIGNATION>
<LIST_TYPE>
<VALUE>UN List</VALUE>
</LIST_TYPE>
<LAST_DAY_UPDATED>
<VALUE>2014-12-17</VALUE>
</LAST_DAY_UPDATED>
<INDIVIDUAL_ALIAS>
<QUALITY>Good</QUALITY>
<ALIAS_NAME>
Mohammad Bakr Zolqadr; Mohammad Bakr Zolkadr; Mohammad Baqer Zolqadir;     Mohammad Baqer Zolqader
</ALIAS_NAME>
</INDIVIDUAL_ALIAS>
<INDIVIDUAL_ADDRESS/>
<INDIVIDUAL_DATE_OF_BIRTH/>
<INDIVIDUAL_PLACE_OF_BIRTH/>
<INDIVIDUAL_DOCUMENT/>
<SORT_KEY>Zolqadr</SORT_KEY>
<SORT_KEY_LAST_MOD>2014-06-18</SORT_KEY_LAST_MOD>
</INDIVIDUAL>
```

I need to access each of the values, blank or otherwise and put them into variables.

I've been trying all kinds of code here is a very basic example, but I can't seem to access the data

```
 foreach($xml->children() as $child)
 {
 echo $child->individuals->individual->dataid;
 }
```

Comment: You can easily access this data via :-
`$xml->individuals->individual[0]->nodename;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop over the `INDIVIDUALS` array and access member objects like this

```
foreach($xml->INDIVIDUALS->INDIVIDUAL as $node){
    echo $node->DATAID . PHP_EOL;
}
```